# what to substitute for thread.sleep

Tags: android

I have a for loop as part of a background thread in my code.  Part way through execution of the code within the loop I want a wait period so I call thread.sleep.  I've discovered that if the phone display closes during the wait period the wait time becomes erratic.   According to the documentation sleep is not time reliable.  So I am wondering what to substitute.  As far as I can see if I create a post delayed sub thread I will loose the continuity within the for loop.  I hope I am wrong and have'nt understood the mechanics properly - any help appreciated.
Ron

Answer (score 1):

One way to deal with the unreliability of sleep() is to add code to measure the actual time you slept. This is often done in animations where a decision can be made to, for instance, skip some number of frames to catch up to real time.

Comment: I must be missing something fundamental.  I have thought about this over the last day and tried messing around with this par t of the code.   No matter what if I  have a for loop and inside it sendMessageDelayed then the loop sends the message but proceeds straight to the next iteration of the loop.  This is what I would expect and what actually happens.   I guess that sleep is intended to fill this need but I cant rely on it.  I must be missing something in the concept of threads and handlers IN RELATION TO FOR LOOPS.

Comment: I hope someone can point me to something that will help.   I have Rito Meier's book but that doesnt seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use Handler and call [postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29)? I honestly can't claim how reliable that will be or if it fits your problem but I use it for small regular updates.

You might also look into [Partial Wake Locks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) to see if that might give you more reliable performance.

Comment: If I call postDelayed how do I return to the for loop code as described in my explanation?   I've just looked up PartialWakeLocks and there is a big warning re power consumption.  I particularly want to keep power usage low if I can   and this sleep situation could arise many times.

Comment: The idea behind using postDelayed is to make the thing in your loop a single unit of work that would get called by the handler and it would repost to be run again (in place of the current sleep). On the wake lock yes you have to be careful and without know what you are trying to accomplish I'm not going to argue either way, but I just wanted to give you something to think about.

Comment: Update:  I have thought again and now use a repeating alarm which seems very reliable.  This dispenses with the for loop and I can cancel the alarm when required.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
(...)
Message msg = new Message();
try {
    myHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg,1000);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Hum?",e);
            }
        }
    }


    private Handler myHandler= new Handler() {
        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see android.os.Handler#handleMessage(android.os.Message)
         */
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            //DO WHAT YOU WANT..
        }
    };
```